"Is it rigorous to define an open ball in with the supremum norm?
I have the following definitions:

The open ball in the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, centered at the zero function and with radius $\|f\|$ (where $\|f\| > 0$ and the norm is the supremum norm), is defined as:

$B(0, \|f\|)$ In the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$.

The set $A$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ is defined as:
$
A = \{g \in C([0,1]) : \|g\| < \|f\|\}, \quad \text{with } \|f\| > 0.
$

My questions are:
Is it correct to say that $B(0,\|f\|) $=$A$?
Is it valid and rigorous to define the ball $B(0, \|f\|)$ in this space of continuous functions?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

It's not clear where is your confusion. You write the exact same set when defined $B(0,|f|)$ and when defined $A$. Why would they be different if they are defined in the exact same way? Are you really asking "If $X=Z$ and $Y=Z$, is it correct to say that $X=Y$?"

You're right ,I made some corrections.

Yes, this is valid and rigorous. Note that $||f||$ is just a non-negative real for any continuous function on [0, 1] (positive in your case). When you replace $||f||$ with say fixed $r$, it may be more apparent that the RHS is exactly the same, with the only difference being the label on the left.
More generally we could define $B(f, r)$ to be the set of continuous functions $g$ on $[0, 1]$ such that $||f-g|| < r$. I do wonder what exactly you're worried wouldn't be valid or rigorous - as long as the supremum norm itself is well-defined on our space we are fine.
Edit: To clarify, open balls are defined in metric spaces, so what I assume you're actually asking is whether $C([0, 1])$ is a metric space. Any norm induces a metric $d(x, y) = ||x-y||$, so assuming you're happy that the supremum is indeed a norm on this space, we define $B(f, r)$ as $\{g \in C([0, 1]) : d(f, g) < r\}$. I'll leave it to you to verify this does indeed mean $B(0, ||f||) = A$.
